# OpenSource applications that uses Large/Huge pages on Linux

Tags: linux, memory-management, tlb

I was looking for open-source applications that make use of *large/huge memory pages* (OS memory pages with size > 4KB) on Linux (x86-64). I wanted study how large pages are used today. Can somebody points me to few such applications?

Thanks

Arka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memcached and MySQL both have the option to use large pages if they're available.

Answer (score 1):

And finally, with recent Linux kernels having support for *transparent hugepages*, programs can/will make use of it without knowing they do.